# Sending a string format date from html to javascript function. Javascript receives only a different year

Tags: javascript, string, function

I'm sending the expected return date (of a book to its owner) to a javascript function.

```
<td onclick="setApproved(@item.SchoolBook.Id,0,@item.Requestor.Id,@item.ExpectedReturnDate)"><button class="button-green" title="Approve">Approve</button></td>
```

When debugging I see that @item.ExpectedReturnDate which is a string is rendered properly, but the function receives something else entirely. 
For example: @item.ExpectedReturnDate is 2019-06-27, the javascript function receives 1986.
The Javascript function:

```
function setApproved(bookId, type, requestorId,erd) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "/Books/SetApproved",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            bookId: bookId,
            type: type,
            requestorId: requestorId,
            erd: erd
        },
        success: function (response) {
            if (response == "success")
                //reload page
                location.href = `/Books/BooksToLend`;
            else
                if (response == "fail")
                    //load error page
                    location.href = `/User/Error`;
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            location.href = `/User/Error`;
        },
        error: function (response) {
            location.href = `/User/Error`;
        }
    });
}
```

Here are snapshots of the debugging in the browser:

What is sent to function

[image]

What function receives

[image]

I would appreciate all help on this. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are sending the date like a number, but then you have the `-` character.

For it to work you should send the date as a string, or creating a new `Date` object.

Something like this:

```js
setApproved(5, 0, 323214, 2019-06-27)
setApproved(5, 0, 323214, '2019-06-27')
setApproved(5, 0, 323214, new Date('2019-06-27'))

function setApproved(bookId, type, requestorId,erd) {
  console.log(bookId);
  console.log(type);
  console.log(requestorId);
  console.log(erd);
}
```

Comment: if it worked. you should mark my answer as the valid one